# Want to store n matrices in a single list in python without using numpy. i am trying to achieve one copy of every matrix in population

Tags: python-3.x, list, matrix

```
import random
import copy
print("Enter the order of matrix")
size = 2
matrix =[]
population = []
pop = []
order = int(input())
for k in range(size):
    for i in range(order):      
        a =[] 
        for j in range(order):       
            a.append(random.randint(1,4)) 
        matrix.append(a) 
        print("a" , a)
        print("Matrix \t",matrix)
        print("\n")
    print(k)
    pop.append(matrix)
    print("POP \t",pop)
    population = population + copy.deepcopy(pop)
    matrix.clear()
print("Population \n", population")
```

I tried this but it appends the matrices k times in the list. Is there any way this can be done .

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you hope to achieve? The observed behavior results from the fact that object variables in python are always references. As you do not restart `matrix` but only clear it, its reference remains the same. Thus `pop` contains a list of copies of the same reference. In the construction of `population` you use `deepcopy`, thus copying the actual content of the object. Consequenctly, `population` contains one copy of the first matrix, then two copies of the second, then three of the third etc.

You could also shortly use

```
pop = [ [ [ random.randint(1,4) for j in range(order) ] for i in range(order) ] for k in range(size) ]
```

Comment: I want one copy of each matrix in population

Comment: What is then the difference between `pop` and `population`?

Comment: pop will be empty as soon as i clear matrix and popualtion is just  a copy all the matrix in the pop

Comment: Can you give more of a motivation for this construction? Why do you think that `pop` will be empty at any stage? As it is, it keeps on containing the previously appended copies of the reference/pointer to the unchanged `matrix` container object.

Comment: As soon as i clear matrix it will also clear pop isn't it ? As pop is just a pointer to the location . can you help me achieve what i am trying to ? Use your own way

Comment: No, if not explicitly called, pop is not cleared. The object `matrix` still exists, all the entries in `pop` point to it. Add some print statements to see the effect. // I do not see what more than the existing code you would need, assign it to `population` directly instead of the intermediate `pop`.

Comment: but the it dosen't store as a matrix it will store as individual rows.And i want to store as a matrix